# What things in CORE Perl set the ERRNO ($!) on success?

Tags: perl, error-handling

According to [PerlIO::scalar](https://perldoc.perl.org/PerlIO/scalar.html) you can open a filehandle to a scalar,

```
open my $fh, ">",  \$scalar or die;
```

How come `$!` gets set when you use this though?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use Test::More tests => 3;

is ( $!, '', '$! is not set' );

my $output;
open ( my $fh, '>', \$output );
print $fh "Hello, World!";

is ( $output, "Hello, World!", "Got the right output" );
is ( $!, '', '$! is not set' );
```

This is really weird: `fork` returns the `pid` so you determine failure by looking at `$!`. I thought `$!` only got set on failure though. The docs make it clear that this variable doesn't get cleared on success,

> Many system or library calls set `errno` if they fail, to indicate the cause of failure. **They usually do not set `errno` to zero if they succeed.** This means `errno`, hence `$!`, is meaningful only *immediately* after a failure - `perldoc perlvar`

So generally you have to clear `$!` after a *failure*. But should we always clear it after a *success* too? What things set `$!` on success?

Comment: Hmm, "In contrast to $! and $^E , which are set only if an error condition is detected,.." that would indeed indicate my first comment is wrong :|

Comment: "So generally you have to clear `$!` after a failure" no, you don't have to clear `$!`.  you should only be looking at `$!` after a failure; trying to keep it in a dependable state that you can check any time you want is not a path you want to go down.

Comment: You never have to clear `$!` except before a syscall which does not have another error indication like `getpwent` and friends. It is likely being set by a syscall being run as part of the opening process whose failure is just part of the branching logic.

Comment: I think it might also help the general understanding here to point out that `$!` is for syscall errors, which is a specific unixy thing; it is *not* a Perl high level error mechanism on its own, it may be set by syscalls that may or may not be directly relevant to what you tried to do. `open` simply returns false when a syscall error has occurred that causes the operation to fail, and relies on `$!` having been set appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer rewritten**

In the question I said,

> This is really weird: `fork` returns the pid so you determine failure by looking at `$!`.

This was not true: `fork` indicates failure by returning `undef` for the pid. From `perldoc -f fork`,

> It returns the child pid to the parent process, 0 to the child process, or `undef` if the fork is unsuccessful.

From the [bug report](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/issues/17780), you can see:

> There are some cases where you have to clear it beforehand because no other mechanism is given to indicate an error -  Grinnz

But, it appears `fork` is not one of those cases. So it seems like *anything* can put anything in `$!`. That is to say, even when an error has not occurred `$!` could be populated. But *only* when you rely on `$!` for the presence of an error should you clear it beforehand, and you should never rely on `$!` for error-status unless required.

---

*[Original bug on Perl opened here](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/issues/17780)*

Answer (score 2):

> *How come $! gets set when you use this though?*

`$!` gets set by successful calls all the time. That's why `$!` is only meaningful when a function indicates `$!` is meaningful (by returning an error).

> *Original bug on Perl opened here*

Not a bug in Perl. As per the documentation you quoted, `$!` is only meaningful after a failed call, so the fact that you assign meaning to its value after a successful call is a bug in *your* code.

> *So generally you have to clear `$!` after a failure.*

You don't ever need to clear `$!`.

> *This is really weird: `fork` returns the pid so you determine failure by looking at `$!`.*

No, [`fork`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fork.html) returns `undef` on error. Only check `$!` if `fork` returns `undef`.

```
my $pid = fork();
defined($pid)
   or die($!);

if (!$pid) {
   my $rv;
   if (!eval { $rv = child(); 1 }) {
      # Let's be careful in case the stringification of $@ fails.
      my $e = $@;
      eval { warn($e); 1 }
         or warn("Unknown error");

      # Attempt to return something meaningful like Perl does.
      exit( $! || ($? >> 8) || 255 );
   }

   exit($rv);
}

waitpid($pid, 0);
```

Comment: "You don't ever need to clear $!." what about when you detect errors from `getpwent`

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: `getpwent` and similar is a special case (of course, not the only one) because the syscall itself is badly designed. See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getpwent.3.html#RETURN_VALUE

Comment: Perl's `getpwent` is not guaranteed to return to `$!` unchanged on success, so the method described in the docs for the C call would be unreliable for Perl's call. It would be up to Perl itself to do `errno = ENOERROR;` and check `errno` on return. And it appears to do that. The docs for Perl's `getpwent` says it returns a single meaningless true value on error. So the correct way to call it (if you want to check for errors) is to use `while (1) { my $count = my ($name) = getpwent(); $count != 1 or die($!); last if !$count; ... }` @Grinnz

Comment: It says it returns a meaningless true value if the entry does not exist, this is relevant to functions like `getpwnam` and does not occur when using the iterating `getpwent`/`getgrent` functions which are not looking for a specific entry. (The docs are probably in need of some clarification)

Comment: @Grinnz Good point. There may not be a reliable way of checking if `getpwent` failed. And the docs do need some clarification.